# init method in kotlin dependent on order of variables and init method declaration

Tags: android, kotlin

In kotlin, for any class which has an `init` method (I found this example in a ViewModel) why is the following valid:

```
val variable1 = "nothing"

fun example1() {
    variable1
    variable2
}

val variable2 = "nothing"
```

the order in which I declared the variables and the method did not make a difference, I can still access `variable2` inside the method, however,

```
val variable1 = "nothing"

val variable2 = "nothing"

init {
    variable1
    variable2
    variable3
}

val variable3 = "an issue"
```

gives an error saying that `variable3` must be initialized? See this image, I know that example1() isn't used, but it doesn't make a difference if I use it somewhere [image]

Comment: I get the same compile error in your first snippet as you report for the second snippet.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's actually pretty interesting, see my attached picture

Comment: Ah, actually, I misread the first snippet. You are comparing apples (`init`) and oranges (`fun`).

Comment: is init handled differently compared to functions then ?

Comment: `init` blocks are treated as akin to property initializers. In particular, quoting [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors): "During an instance initialization, the initializer blocks are executed in the same order as they appear in the class body, interleaved with the property initializers"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to CommonsWare for pointing it out.

initializer blocks are not constructors, they are simply used for initializing values, you can even have multiple init blocks as well. However, an initializer block is not a function and therefore it is dependent on the order of variables being declared and used